# To upload or download from Dropbox

Tags: webservices

Can it be possible to download or upload data from/to Dropbox from Salesforce using webs service API if any provided.

Comment: There is an Apex framework available to provide functionality for Dropbox API callouts [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/ffhttp-dropbox?files=1). Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any API or URL that you can all from Apex?